# How to move object into the screen from outside via jQuery transition

Tags: jquery, html, animation, css-transitions, transition

I want to create a test object that enters the screen from the left upon page load using jQuery.

I have placed:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('animtext').transition({ x: 200 }, 500, 'ease');
</script>
```

before the `<head>`, and the CSS for `.animtext` is:

```
.animtext {
background-image:url('../render_01.jpg');
width:400px;
height:400px;
}
```

Yet nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me how I can simply get an object to transition using jQuery?

**** Thanks Wiley for response. Still no joy, have no idea what I'm doing wrong!

I do have the relevant .js files installed.

The code now looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />

<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.transit.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/customtransit.js'></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js">       

</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.animtext').transition({ x: 200px }, 500, 'ease');
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="animtext"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Still no luck... any help gratefully received.

Comment: Are you including `jquery.js` or `jquery.min.js` somewhere?

Comment: Maybe you can do it this way: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-transitions-javascript/

Comment: It shouldn't be before `<head>` but before `</head>` or `</body>`. Preferably the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `animtext` is a class you are missing the `.` for the class selector

```
$('.animtext')
```

Also wrap your code inside a document.ready function if you are placing your code "inside" the head

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // or $(function(){ which is shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){
     // your code yere
});
```

The other alternative would be to put your code right before the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: you need to import jQuery before your other js files because they are more than likely dependant on jQuery

Comment: @user2339879 here's an example of it working fine [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GeADD/)

Comment: SORTED. Thank you Wirey, et al... wasn't working because jquery.min.js wasn't called before jquery.transit.x and customtransit.js, as you said. Temperamental! Thanks!!